# Jquery - How to parse the JSON array?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, parsing

I would like to parse through jquery. When I want to parse, there is an error - undefined.

This is my code:

PHP

```
try { 

session_start();

require '../SqlConfig.php';


 if(isset($_POST["user_name"]) && isset($_POST["user_password"])) {
 {  

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["user_name"]) . "' AND " . "user_password='". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["user_password"]) ."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$jsonresult = array();

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $thisResult = array();

    $thisResult["user_auth"] = 1;
    $thisResult["user_id"] = $row['user_id'];
    $thisResult["user_name"] = $row['user_name'];

    $_SESSION["user_auth"] = 1;
    $_SESSION["user_id"] = $row['user_id'];
    $_SESSION["user_name"] = $row['user_name'];

    $jsonresult[] = $thisResult;
  }
  echo json_encode($jsonresult);
  mysql_close();
  }

}
}
catch(Exception $e) 
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**JSON ARRAY:**

```
[{"user_auth":1,"user_id":"11","user_name":"Jenan"},
 {"user_auth":1,"user_id":"15","user_name":"Jenan2"},
 {"user_auth":1,"user_id":"16","user_name":"Jenan3"}]
```

**JQUERY**

```
getAuthentification: function(username, password)
    {
        $.post('ActionScripts/Authentification.php',{
            user_name: username, 
            user_password: password
        }, function(data) 
        {
          $.each(data, function(key, value){
                alert(value.user_auth +' - '+ value.user_id +' - '+ value.user_name);
            });


        });
    }
```

Here is the error: The result is undefined - undefined - undefined. And an endless cycle. -

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
                alert(value.user_auth +' - '+ value.user_id +' - '+ value.user_name);
            });
```

data -

```
 [{"user_auth":1,"user_id":"11","user_name":"Jenan"},
 {"user_auth":1,"user_id":"15","user_name":"Jenan2"},
 {"user_auth":1,"user_id":"16","user_name":"Jenan3"}]
```

alert - output - `undefined - undefined - undefined`

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Debug it by doing a `console.log(data)` right before your `$.each`.

Comment: Data -  [{"user_auth":1,"user_id":"11","user_name":"Jenan"},
 {"user_auth":1,"user_id":"15","user_name":"Jenan2"},
 {"user_auth":1,"user_id":"16","user_name":"Jenan3"}]
in console.log(data). I tried it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
getAuthentification: function(username, password)
    {
        $.post('ActionScripts/Authentification.php',{
            user_name: username, 
            user_password: password
        }, function(data) 
        {
          $.each(data, function(key, value){
                alert(value.user_auth +' - '+ value.user_id +' - '+ value.user_name);
            });


        },"json");
    }
```

all i added was `,"json"` to the end to tell jquery that it should expect a json response instead of a string response.